# Alfresco workflow behaviour documentation

Tags: workflow, alfresco

I'm learning how to develop advanced workflow in Alfresco and I find things like `bpm_assignee, bpm_workflowDueDate, taskInstance, initiator` and so on in custom behaviour JavaScript API code examples but I can't find documentation for it.

Can somebody point me to the right direction?

Comment: Thanks for the answers, in these links I can find some info but is spread and superfluous. I nedd a list of exposed "objects" in the workflow, expression syntax, "objects" attriubtes and so on. I need strict and formal documentation, not a guy telling things about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the wiki page Tahir cited...

The official documentation on Alfresco workflows lives here for Alfresco 4:
http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/topic/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/topics/wf-howto.html

And here for Alfresco 3.4:
http://docs.alfresco.com/3.4/topic/com.alfresco.Enterprise_3_4_0.doc/topics/wf-howto.html

You may also be interested in an advanced workflow tutorial. This one is for Alfresco 4 and uses Activiti:
http://ecmarchitect.com/images/articles/alfresco-workflow/advanced-workflow-article-2ed.pdf

This one uses older versions of Alfresco and jBPM:
http://ecmarchitect.com/images/articles/alfresco-workflow/advanced-workflow-article.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Go through the [WorkflowAdministration](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/WorkflowAdministration) Wiki page, there you'll find all the info you need.